# Firebase get grandparent object from grandchild key

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I try to retrieve all the grand parent objects when a grandchild key is matched. In the Firebase realtime database below, I have for example the sensor key "-LNVBiM1SGoAFvlMfi1V", and I need to retrieve with it all the orders objects where this key is found (04TBR7 in this example).

I know the database structure might not be perfect but there is no possibility to modify it for now.

I tried the following code but it is not right, I guess the `equalTo` is not working since it is an Object:

```
db.ref('/orders').orderByChild('sensors').equalTo(sensor_id).once('value', snapshot => {
// my snapshot is always empty ...
});
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: @AlexMamo I am not sure to understand, 04TBR7 is what I am trying to retrieve, or the whole node object.

Comment: Hey Yoann. Did you get anywhere with this? I tried to help with an answer below. Did you have a chance to check that out, and try it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to use `orderByChild("sensors")` in the way you're trying, as it checks the **value** of the `sensors` property (not the key).

It's important to keep in mind that Firebase database queries work on a flat list of nodes. So you can search for a specific order property across all orders, and you can search sensors under a specific order. But you can not search across all sensors for all orders.

Since you say you can't modify the data structure, that unfortunately means you'll have to load the entire JSON and find the matching nodes client-side.

Also see:

- [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value)
- [Firebase Query Double Nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested)